# Laravel 5.2 Login not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have created a new Laravel 5.2 installation. And I have run the following command to install the default Laravel authentication;

```
php artisan make:auth
```

The registration form works but the login just redirects home without logging in. And displays no errors when when I enter the wrong credentials.

This is my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'BaseController@index');

Route::get('/tutors', 'TutorsController@Index');
Route::get('/tutors/myrequest', 'TutorsController@RequestTutor');
Route::get('/tutors/{id}', 'TutorsController@show')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
Route::get('/tutors/{GUID}', 'TutorsController@TutorByGUID')->where(['id' => '[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+']);


/********************Authentication routes**********************************/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
});
```

This is code from the `AuthController`:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;


protected $redirectTo = '/';

public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

This is the `BaseController` which contains the home method;

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Services\InterfaceService;
use App\Repositories\TutorRepository;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BaseController extends Controller {

    protected $TutorRepository;


    protected $InterfaceService;
    public function __construct(InterfaceService $InterfaceService, TutorRepository $TutorRepository)
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest');
        $this->InterfaceService = $InterfaceService;
        $this->TutorRepository = $TutorRepository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $tutors = $this->TutorRepository->all();
        $page_info = \Config::get('constants.App.Pages.home');
        $this->InterfaceService->SetPageInfo($page_info);
        return view('home', ['TopTutors'=>$tutors]);
    }

} ?>
```

This is code from the login view.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}" id="login_form">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="mj_login_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mj_toppadder20">
                <div class="form-group  pull-left">
                    <div class="mj_checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check2" name="remember">
                        <label for="check2"></label>
                    </div>
                    <span> remember me</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mj_toppadder20">
                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                    <span><a href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">forget password ?</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mj_pricing_footer">
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#login_form').submit()">login Now</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please also include the login view file.

Comment: I think I am supposed to add the Auth malware but I am not sure how to configure it with the routes. My attempts have resulted in an infinite loop on the login page. I have also looked at adding \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class, to the Kernel.php $middlewareGroups but that did not work either.

Comment: As of v5.2.27, all routes in `app/Http/routes.php` are already included in the `web` middleware group. Try removing the route group surrounding your `Route::auth()`.

Comment: Please, paste home controlller

Comment: I am using the BaseController that I have created. I have removed the web middleware group but still the login just redirects me to the home page when the credentials are correct. And there is no indication that I am logged in. But this works when I creating a new account. Some how the errors are now showing on the login page.

Comment: Registration does not work when I remove the middleware group. When I remove Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { around Route::auth(); Registration fails.

Comment: if u want index in basecontroller only accessible by authenticated users. add [auth] middleware to that route. (Web middleware) are required since you need sessions here at this scenario. My question if the login credentials are wrong do u being redirect to the login page with errors?

Comment: The problem has been the users migration not having a primary incremental key. I acidentally changed the id in the users migration to $table->bigInteger( I am noticing Laravel eloquent is not picking any data when there is no Incremetal primary key.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because your `'/'` route is not under the `web` middleware group and you're not using the `auth` middleware for the routes you want to be authenticated

This means that when accessing that route, session is not available, and the `auth` middleware doesn't fire, so authentication doesn't work.

Try to put all the routes in which you want to use session under the `web` middleware group, and for the routes in which you want authentication use the `auth` middleware:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => ['web'] ], function () {     

    /* these routes use 'auth' middleware, so only an authenticated user will access*/
    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'BaseController@index');
    });

    Route::auth();
});
```

**A Note on Laravel version:**

Keep in mind that if you're using Laravel version >= `5.2.27` the middleware `web` is used by default on every route defined in `routes.php` as you can see in  `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web'
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

In that case you can remove you statement for using the `web` middleware group, but you'll only need to use `auth` middleware for the authenticated routes